# GA: Source / Medium not tracked correctly url parameterized

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have defined several advertisements in Google Ads where all their urls are parameterized with utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign. However, when I check the users who arrive from these url in Adquisition > All the traffic > Font/Source still appears like Source/Medium google/cpc and all the urls from the advertisements and extensions are parameterized.

What happen? Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit I:**

Here you've got an screen cap where inside the green rectangle there are visits correctly tagged from the advertisements but inside the red rectangle there are visits which are tagged like google/cpc when all the url from the advertisements have been parameterized to track it correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing that because Google ads has auto tagging for campaigns. The recommended approach is to use it and not override it. Google specifies under what circumstances you should be tagging manually: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033981?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! Already, I've activated auto-tagging, but despite of it, some of the visits which come from the advertisements have like source/medium google/cpc :(

Comment: If you have auto tagging on, then you shouldn’t use utm parameters in your links. Google/Cpc is the standard source/medium. Cpc for cost per click type of ads.

Comment: That's right, but If I tag it I've got in which link I have clicked to access to the web. And I would like to get all the clics associated to source/medium to the parameters that I give in the url's and not google/cpc. I have parameterized all the url's and I get the correct tagged for most of them but then there are some times that the access from the advertisements are tagged with google/cpc when all the links are parameterized and I don't know why is happend this :(

Comment: If you want to know the specific link use the “ad content” dimension to differentiate. Source and Medium should be consistent.

Comment: I think that I have found the origin of these visits tagged like google/cpc. I think that these visits come from clics in Dinamyc Search Advertisements because to create these advertisements have no an own url. Thanks for your appreciated help!!!